# Android facebook sdk 3 - get access token

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using the newest facebook sdk 3. I'm trying to build a class that:

Connects to facebook (application) and returning me:
1. The access token.
2. If it is a first time registration or login.
After I got 1 and 2 I don't need the connection.

I put the facebook application I'd in string as like in SDK sample SessionLoginSample.

My code:

```
private static class FacebookConnector implements Session.StatusCallback{

    private static FacebookConnector instance = null;
    private Fragment mFragment;

    public static FacebookConnector getInctance(Fragment fragment){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new FacebookConnector();
        }
        instance.setFragment(fragment);

        return instance;
    }

    private FacebookConnector(){        
    }

    public Fragment getFragment() {
        return mFragment;
    }

    public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragment = fragment;
    }

    //Facebook fb = new Facebook("app_id");
    //fb.getAccessToken();

    public void connect(){
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if(session == null){
            session = new Session(mFragment.getActivity());
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(mFragment).setCallback(this));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        String token = session.getAccessToken();
        System.out.println(token);
    }

}
```

I got an exception:

```
4-03 17:25:47.651: E/AndroidRuntime(689): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 17:25:47.651: E/AndroidRuntime(689): java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
04-03 17:25:47.651: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:29)
04-03 17:25:47.651: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at com.facebook.Session.<init>(Session.java:224)
04-03 17:25:47.651: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at com.facebook.Session.<init>(Session.java:209)
```

Maybe there are more simple solution?

Comment: Did you also add the meta-data line to your AndroidManifest.xml? Look for com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId in the SessionLoginSample's AndroidManifest. You need that in your manifest as well.

Comment: yes, I added meta data and the appId string to the manifest. I even created my own session with the builder, but it always on CREATED state

Comment: I'm experiencing also, did you manage to fix it?